# DeviceInformation.findAllAsync DeviceInformation returns incorrect name property

Tags: javascript, cordova, bluetooth, uwp

```
var rfcomm = Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Rfcomm;
var sockets = Windows.Networking.Sockets;
var streams = Windows.Storage.Streams;
var deviceInfo = Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation;

var cordova = require('cordova');
module.exports = {

    connService: null,
    connSocket: null,
    connWriter: null,
    connReader: null,
    connDevice: null,

    list: function(successCallback, errorCallback) {

        setTimeout(function() {
            try {
                var selector =
                    rfcomm.RfcommDeviceService.getDeviceSelector(
                        rfcomm.RfcommServiceId.serialPort);
                var parsedDevices = [];

                deviceInfo.findAllAsync(selector, null).then(function(devices) {
                    if (devices.length > 0) {

                        for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
                            parsedDevices.push({
                                id: devices[i].id,
                                name: devices[i].name //returns "SPP-dev" instead of name
                            })
                        }
                        successCallback(parsedDevices);
                    } else {
                        errorCallback("No devices found.");
                    }

                }, function(error) {
                    errorCallback({
                        error: "list",
                        message: error.message
                    });
                });


            } catch (ex) {
                errorCallback(ex);
            }
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

Following code returns in DeviceInfromation.name values like SPP-dev, HM-12, SPP1 or Serial Port, anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

> Following code returns in DeviceInfromation.name values like SPP-dev, HM-12, SPP1 or Serial Port

This is by design and changed in RS1. Your code is querying for the RfcommDeviceServices, and those names match the name of the Rfcomm service on the remote device.

If you are interested in the peripheral name, you must use a selector string targeting the [BluetoothDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothDevice), or get the [parent device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.rfcomm.rfcommdeviceservice#Windows_Devices_Bluetooth_Rfcomm_RfcommDeviceService_Device) from the RfcommDeviceService object.